# No matching unique or primary key for column-list in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE student_detailS01
(USN VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 STUDENT_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 BRANCH VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 CONTACT_NO NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 FATHERS_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 HOME_ADDRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 DOB DATE NOT NULL,
LOCAL_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
EMAIL_ID VARCHAR2(20),
DOJ DATE,
HID NUMBER NOT NULL, 

 PRIMARY KEY (USN,HID)
 );

CREATE TABLE MESS(
S_NO NUMBER NOT NULL,
HID NUMBER REFERENCES STUDENT_DETAILS01(HID),
NO_OF_BREAKFAST INT,
NO_OF_MEALS INT,
AMT_OF_BREAKFAST INT,
AMT_OF_MEALS INT,
TOTAL INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(S_NO)
);
```

`student_details01` table is executed, but mess table gives the following error:

> no matching unique or primary key for this column-list.

Comment: HID NUMBER REFERENCES STUDENT_DETAILS01(HID),  don't refer to the primary key ..

Comment: You've tagged this for three different database engines.  Which one are you actually using?  Your subject says Oracle but your tags have MySQL and SQL Server.  If the primary key of `student_details` is `usn,hid`, your foreign key would have to reference both columns or you would need a separate unique constraint on just `hid`.

Comment: Or at least `hid` should be the leftmost column of the pk.

Comment: Am using oracle 10g

Comment: I want usn & hid both to be primary key in student_details01 nd in mess table i want to refer hid.... any alternative to the code???

Answer (score 0):

The `ORA-2270 : no matching unique or primary key for this column-list` error is quite simple: it happens when the columns we reference in the foreign key do not match a primary key or unique constraint on the parent table. Common reasons for this are

- the parent lacks a constraint altogether
- the parent table's constraint is a compound key and we haven't
  referenced all the columns in the foreign key statement.

To fix your issue try as below:

```
CREATE TABLE MESS
(
   S_NO               NUMBER,
   S_HID              NUMBER,
   S_UNO              VARCHAR (20), --Added Column
   NO_OF_BREAKFAST    INT,
   NO_OF_MEALS        INT,
   AMT_OF_BREAKFAST   INT,
   AMT_OF_MEALS       INT,
   TOTAL              INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT MESS_pk PRIMARY KEY (S_NO),
   CONSTRAINT fk_id_dtls FOREIGN KEY
      (S_HID, S_UNO)
       REFERENCES student_detailS01 (HID, USN)
);
```